# Confusion over using gerund after to

Tags: prepositions

"For companies,depository receipt provides simple way to raising capital and encouraging international investment."

Is the sentence idiomatic?

Because here way is emphasized and to here preposition.
Generally noun form of verb is placed after preposition.Here "raising capital" denotes the objective of the way.

Comment: No, it is definitely not correct or idiomatic English.

Comment: Why? It is not idiomatic.here  to  is preposition

Comment: "Way" does not licence a PP with "to" as head and a gerund-participial clause as its complement.

Comment: It is not correct because (1) _depository receipt_ either needs an article or to be plural in which case it would be _provide_ (2) _simple way_ needs an article (3) it needs to be _to raise_ or _of raising_ and similarly for _encourage_ (4) punctuation marks need to be followed by a space (5) it would read better if _for companies_ came later in the sentence.

Comment: @mdewey Please stop looking in my head while I am writing an answer. It makes my scalp itch.

Comment: @JeffMorrow great minds think alike, my old mum used to say.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not grammatical.

> For companies, depository receipts are a simple way to raise capital and encourage international investment

is grammatical and idiomatic.

**EDIT**: I agree with mdewey’s comment that “provide a way” is more felicitous than “are a way,” but that is stylistic opinion, not grammar. I do not agree that moving “companies” is **necessarily** better stylictically:

> For investors, depository rights provide ….For companies, depository rights provide ….

Good style often depends on context.

Comment: Actually when a certain Objective is meant we can use the v1+ing after infinitive.

Ex: Shaw wrote his plays with a view to transforming the Society.so why is it not idiomatic?

Comment: As was explained in the comment of @BillJ, a construction that is idiomatic when preceded by "view" is not idiomatic if preceded by "way." You are looking for a universal rule, Universal rules are few and far between in English.

Comment: will you refuse "to" used in the sentence is not a preposition?If yes,then i have nothing to say.

Comment: english does not violate rule.can give me an example that violates rule.Every language follows rule.Here "view" is a part of prepositional phrase so gerund is the correct form.

Comment: @BillJ can you refuse "to" used in the question is not a preposition?Even the "to"  does not need to be part of PP but itself is a preposition.That is why sentence is correct in this context.If you want i can show on this website.Why do you people misguide non-native speakers?

Comment: Well, the **RULE** is that “way to” requires an infinitive rather than a gerund as a complement whereas “view” has a different rule. I did not say there are no rules. I said there are few universal rules. The rules about prepositions in English are a mass of inconsistencies. You have had three helpers, all with high reputations, tell you the same thing. Why argue with us?

Comment: see https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.timesofindia.com/city/guwahati/assam-on-way-to-becoming-next-kashmir-himanta-biswa-sarma/amp_articleshow/86335228.cms&ved=2ahUKEwiDxquIwpHzAhVRVH0KHSOiCcs4ChAWegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw1hUyzyoRrGWX3vgJR5VtnN

Comment: am I wrong?If yes then why times of india

Comment: Because that is an entirely different usage of the word "way." "On the way to" does take a gerund. "A way to" takes a bare infinitive. The Times headline is not identifying a method, a "way." It is discussing a trend. "on the way."